# Не работает dns в docker ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dns

Dockerfile1

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial
RUN apt-get install --yes build-essential && \
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys some-key
```

Dockerfile2

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
RUN apt-get install --yes build-essential && \
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys some-key
```

/etc/docker/daemon.json

```
 {                                                                                                     
      "storage-driver": "overlay2",                                                                     
      "dns": ["127.0.0.1", "172.16.0.250"]                                                             
 }
```

Первый конфиг докера работает, второй же падает при попытке резолва keyserver.ubuntu.com. В чём может быть проблема?
При чём, если поменять dns-серверы местами, то всё работает. Такое ощущение, что если в docker если разрезолвить по через первый сервер не удалось, то он не пробует остальные

Answer (score 1):

Если первый днс-сервер отвечает NXDOMAIN (нет записи с таким именем), остальные днс-сервера не опрашиваются, т.к. nxdomain - не ошибка.
Вероятно на днс-сервере на локалхосте (127.0.0.1)  не настроена пересылка запросов (опция forwarders в bind)

Comment: Думал об этом, поэтому решил поменять на несуществующий ip, тоже самое, а ведь ему в таком случае точно никто не ответит